# Resized Primary Partition, Filesystem Size Not Updating

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, drive, boot-partition

I moved and resized by /boot primary partition using gparted.

```
 sudo parted /dev/sda print

 Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system  Flags
  1      1049kB  256MB  255MB   primary   ext2
  2      257MB   128GB  128GB   extended
  5      257MB   128GB  128GB   logical                lvm
  3      253GB   256GB  3146MB  primary   ext2         boot
```

Yet, the size of the filesystem remains the same:

```
 df

 Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
 /dev/sda1          240972    235317          0 100% /boot
 ...
```

I've tried to extend the filesystem:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

But it returns:

```
The filesystem is already 248832 (1k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confusing your partition **mounted** at /boot with your partition **flagged** as boot.

When you call

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

You are attempting to resize partition 1 (/dev/sda1)

According to your parted output, this is partition 1:

```
 1      1049kB  256MB  255MB   primary   ext2
```

which correctly outputs that it's already ~255MB long:

```
The filesystem is already 248832 (1k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I suspect that you meant partition 3, the partition **flagged** as boot:

```
 3      253GB   256GB  3146MB  primary   ext2         boot
```

**Can you please try resizing that filesystem by doing this?**

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3
```

Comment: This can also be done alot more easily using a GUI tool such as **gparted**.  If you need to modify OS partitions, just boot your machine using the Ubuntu Install CD/USB Key, run the "Terminal" app and type in "sudo gparted". :-)